# How to configure controller bluetooth to webvr

Tags: aframe, webvr

Sorry for my ignorance, but I have a question about controller for webvr

Can I configure this [controller](https://d234pm57oy3062.cloudfront.net/product-58f58e08ba7ce-HTB1DIRBQXXXXXXbaXXXq6xXFXXXn.jpg) para webVR, that is events with buttons, movement of cursor etc?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your controller returns pose information, A-Frame components like laser-controls should work.  If all you need is the buttons, my button-controls (https://github.com/DougReeder/aframe-button-controls) should work. Otherwise, you'll need to use the GamePad API: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much for your answer! I'll check the information. :)